# How to determine equality for two ES6 class instances?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, equality

How to determine equality between two **ES6 class object instances**? For example:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {    
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}

(new Rectangle(1, 1)) === (new Rectangle(1, 1))
(new Rectangle(3, 0)) === (new Rectangle(9, 3))
```

The last two statements return false, but I want it to return true, to compare the instance properties, instead of the object references.

Comment: There is no operator overloading in JavaScript, and objects are compared by reference, not by property values. You'll need to define your own function to compare them.

Comment: Well.... I want a jaguar, doesn't mean it will happen. You are doing a comparison between two memory references that are not pointing to the same address, this returning true would be wrong.

You need to implement a method on the prototype of the constructor function that will recognize it's children by some means, the `===` is not what will get you the results sadly.

Comment: The best method would probably be to create an `.equals()` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a method to the `Rectangle` class:

```
class Rectangle {
  constructor(height, width) {    
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  equals(rect) {
    return this.width == rect.width && this.height == rect.height;
  }
}
```